# positioning a nav bar so it's fixed

Tags: html, css, navigation, position

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Vasilios Lambos</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
<a class="logo" href="home.html"><img src="VL-Logo.png"></a>
</div>
<nav role="navigation">
<div class="Nav">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a></li> 
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <a href="process.html">Process</a></li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Vaslios Lambos</h1>
<p>Industrial and Interaction Designer</p>

</div>

<div class="info">
<div class="container">
<h3>Overview</h3>
<p> ### </p>

</div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
<h3>Soft & Hard skills</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Adobe Suite</li>
    <li>Axure RP</li>
    <li>HTML/CSS/Javascript</li>

</ul>

</div>


</body>
</html>

@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

body {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #FFF;
margin:auto;
/*border:2px solid red;*/
}

div.header {
float:right;
}


div.Nav a{
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0px;
padding:32px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
/*border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;*/
 }


div.Nav a:hover {
 background-color: orange;
 }

div.jumbotron{
position:relative;
top:30px;
background-color: #000;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
height:400px;
} 

div.info {
background-color: #FFF;
color:black;
padding:20px;
height:400px;
}
div.footer{
background-color:#000;
color:white;
height:400px;
clear:both;
padding:20px;
}
```

I want to make a navigational bar be fixed on the site so when you scroll up and down it stays in one place. I am also planning to display images and design work and interfaces designed in photoshop and are put together in Axure.

my site is updated with this code and can be seen at vasilioslambos.com

Comment: Can you put code in Fiddle or as text instead of image?

Comment: Please include code, not screenshots of code. This helps us to help you, because we can easily copy the code to try it ourselves, and it helps search engines index the question properly.

Comment: Thank you for your post! Can you update your post to display a question? I see that the tabs disappear, but what are you really trying to achieve at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Best to wrap everything you want to be static in a new div i.e.

```
<body>
<div id="fixed">
<div class="header">
<a class="logo" href="home.html"><img src="VL-Logo.png"></a>
</div>
<nav role="navigation">
<div class="Nav">
    <a href="home.html">Home</a></li> 
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <a href="process.html">Process</a></li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

css

```
#fixed{position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:9999;/*High z-index so nothing can hide it*/
background:rgb(255,255,255);
padding:5px 0;
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

and change this

```
div.Nav a{
background-color: #FFF;
color: #000;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0px;
padding:5px 32px;/* dont need 32px on the top, left, bottom, right*/
text-transform:uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
/*border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;*/
 }
```

This will affect the jumbotron so you'd probably do better not constantly using the position property on all of your sections. I only use it as an override if my html code doesn't automatically align.

> psst remove the position property from jumbotron and it'll fit into
>   place

Comment: I am confused could you explain further. I have a height on div.jumbotron. thank you

Comment: Sorry that answer was to a different question.

Comment: When I added the div and css the nav bar was knocked out of place and the image lost it's location

Comment: how do i make a solid menu bar?